# Empty XmlHttp responsetext (only Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem with my chat script in Google Chrome.
Sometimes the responsetext is empty until you reload the page, but sometimes it's working well. It opens a xmlhttp connection every second and if the first good the ones after that also good.
In Firefox it's always good.

```
var url = "text.php";
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = myfunc;
xmlHttp.send(null);

function myfunc()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete")
    {
        var msg = xmlHttp.responseText;
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details, the content of `myfunc` for example ? You can edit your question to do so.

Comment: Edited. myfunc() is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
var xmlHttp;
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "text.php";
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        var msg = xmlHttp.responseText;
        alert(msg);
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: I will try it and reply soon.

Comment: It's working almost always, but sometimes not.
But it seems to be working more often.
After pressing „Shift + F5” it's sometimes good.

Comment: it will work for sure for IE7 and higher version browsers. when is it not working ?

Comment: it is because the above script works on webpage load so you have to refresh it to work . If you want it to work on button click put the above code in a function and call that function in onclick event

Comment: But I don't understand why it works sometimes and why it doesn't sometimes.

Comment: The above code works on page load and retrieves the response. If you want it to work on button click put the above code in a function and call that function in onclick event of the button

Comment: It doesn't work sometimes, but most of the time it's correct.

Comment: I don't know, i think it's random.

Comment: You told you are getting the result when you refresh .It means the code is working because the above code works on page load

Comment: I don't get result always when I refresh, but most of the time I get.

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( at all!  xmlHttp.responseText is empty still

Comment: var xmlhttp;

try{
    
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  catch(e){
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }

 
    }
       
            
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "../update.php", false);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html");
      xmlhttp.send(xmlDoc.xml); @SarathSprakash